# Usage of index in R raster setValues function

Tags: raster, r

I have a `RasterStack` object and want to replace some values at a set of indices in all layers. That doesn't work as expected, however. `setValues` replaces all values even though I pass a set of indices. The following code illustrates my problem:

```
library (raster)

# Create sample object
r1 <- raster (nrows = 10, ncols = 10)
r2 <- raster (nrows = 10, ncols = 10)
r3 <- raster (nrows = 10, ncols = 10)
values (r1) <- runif (ncell (r1))
values (r2) <- runif (ncell (r2))
values (r3) <- runif (ncell (r3))
rst <- stack (r1, r2, r3)

# Pixel IDs to replace
indexvalues <- c (1, 2, 99)

# Values to substitute
newvalues <- c (10, -10, NA)

result <- setValues (rst, newvalues, index = indexvalues)

# All values are replaced, not just the ones at the indices
plot (result)


### This is what I would expect
values (r1) [indexvalues] <- newvalues
values (r2) [indexvalues] <- newvalues
values (r3) [indexvalues] <- newvalues
rst <- stack (r1, r2, r3)

plot (rst)
```

How can I get `setValues` to produce my expected result or is there something else wrong?

Comment: The `index` parameter is only valid if `rst` is a `RasterLayerSparse` class object. What's wrong with your `values(r1)[index]<-values` method? I suspect the `index` parameter for `RasterLayerSparse` objects exists because direct value replacement might not work for sparse rasters. They're a rare thing....

Comment: Thank you, that clears it up! There's nothing wrong with `values(r1)[index]<-values` per se, it's just a bit cumbersome when dealing with a lot of layers and I thought I could do a one liner instead.

Comment: It would be more efficient, and clearer, to do `r1[index] <- values`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `values` of a stack is a matrix, so you can directly replace rows to change all the pixels in a location in a stack without having to do each layer separately:

Test stack, using fixed values per layer to make it easier to see the changes than random numbers:

```
> r1 = raster(matrix(50,10,10))
> r2 = raster(matrix(60,10,10))
> r3 = raster(matrix(70,10,10))
> 
> rst <- stack (r1, r2, r3)
> 
> plot(rst)
```

Then replace values by row:

```
> values(rst)[indexvalues,] =  newvalues
> 
> plot(rst)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you even need `values`? Cant you just use the brackets `rst[indexvalues] <-  newvalues` or for a specific layer `rst[[1]][indexvalues] <- newvalues`

Comment: I *think* `values()` is safer when you have rasters that are loaded-on-demand....

Comment: FWIW: I agree with Jeffrey. `rst[i] <- v` is more direct, as intended, and could be memory safe.